# Laravel include an extended partial

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5

Im trying to include a partial, that extends another partial.

Like `@include('B')`and B  looks like

```
@extends('A') 
@section('content') 
Some stuff here 
@stop
```

But it seems that only `Some stuff here`gets displayed, but not the things of partial A. Do you have any fixes for that?

Thanks

Comment: I tried to reproduce your structure and it worked for me. It might be that what you posted is a little too abstract, and I might have tried something slightly different. Please post a full example that showcases the entire inheritance structure between all relevant views (including the contents of view `A`).

Comment: After a night of sleeping I found the source of the problem: I used the section "body" twice. You and I wouldn't have been able to figure it out with just the code of the partials.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to use partial **B** that extends template **A**

If you need to append data, you can use the `@parent` or `@append` notation, like so:

```
@extends('A')

@section('content')
    @parent

    Some stuff here
@stop
```

This will append parent data from template A's content section, inside template B

More info at [Laravel's Blade documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates#blade-templating)

Answer (score 0):

Actually this works. The problem here was the non-unique use of the @section Identifier. (In the base Template and in the partial)